# The type ' ' already contains a definition for ' '

Tags: c#

I am building a contact managers application on a console application and I have made a contact object class but I keep getting the Error:
The type 'Contact' already contains a definition for 'ContactTypes'. 
I am not sure how to fix this

```
class Contact
{

    //private member variables
    private String _firstName;
    private String _lastName;
    public ContactTypes _contactTypes;
    private String _phoneNumber;
    private String _emailAddress;




    //Public constructor that takes five arguments
    public Contact()
    {
        //Call the appropriate setter (e.g. FirstName) to set the member variable value
        /*GetFirstName = firstName;
        GetLastName = lastName;
        ContactTypes = contactTypes;
        GetPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        GetEmailAddress = emailAddress;*/

    }


    /*********************************************************************
     * Public accessors used to get and set private member variable values
     *********************************************************************/
    //Public  ContactTypes accessor
      public ContactTypes ContactTypes
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _contactTypes;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == null)
       {
                throw new Exception("ContactType must have a value");
       }
            else
       {
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _contactTypes = value;
       }
        }
    } 
    enum ContactTypes { Family, Friend, Professional }
    //Public FirstName accessor: Pascal casing
    public String GetFirstName
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("First name must have a value");
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _firstName = value;
            }
        }
    }

    //Public LastName accessor: Pascal casing
    public String GetLastName
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
                throw new Exception("Last name must have a value");
            else
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _lastName = value;
        }
    }



    //Public PhoneNumber accessor
    public String GetPhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            /*bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(value, @"/d{3}-/d{3}-/d{4}");
            if (!isValid)
            {
                throw new Exception("PhoneNumber must have a value");
            }
            else
            {
                _phoneNumber = value;
            }*/
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("PhoneNumber must have a value");
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _phoneNumber = value;
            }
        }
    }



    //Public Email accessor
    public String GetEmailAddress
    {
        get
        {
            //Return member variable value
            return _emailAddress;
        }
        set
        {
            //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
            if (value == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("EmailAddress must have a value");
            }
            else
            {
                //Otherwise set member variable value
                _emailAddress = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Already posted and accepted an answer for the same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two class members that have the same name:

```
public ContactTypes ContactTypes
enum ContactTypes { Family, Friend, Professional }
```

Simply rename one of them.

Or, as suggested in the comment you can move the `ContactTypes` enum definition outside the `Contact` class.

Comment: Alternatively, move the ContactTypes enum to it's own CS file.

Answer (score 0):

You have class and enum with the same name ContactTypes. That is why you have received an error. Consider to rename class.